# How to get non-NaN elements' index and the value from a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a big data frame with lots of NaN, I want to store it into a smaller data frame which stores all the indexes and the values of the non-NaN, non-zero values.

```
dff = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,3), columns=list('ABC'))
dff.iloc[0:2,0] = np.nan
dff.iloc[2,2] = np.nan
dff.iloc[1:4,1] = 0
```

The data frame may look like this:

```
    A              B             C
0   NaN         -2.268882      0.337074
1   NaN         0.000000       1.340350
2   -1.526945   0.000000       NaN
3   -1.223816   0.000000      -2.185926
```

I want a data frame looks like this:

```
0   B  -2.268882
0   C  0.337074
1   C  1.340350
2   A  -1.526945
3   A  -1.223816
4   C  -2.185926
```

How can I do it quickly, as i have a relatively big data frame, thousands by thousands...

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `0` with `np.nan` and `.stack()` the result [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

If there's a chance that you have all `np.nan` values in `rows` after `.replace()`, you could do `.dropna(how='all')` before `.stack()` to reduce the number of rows to pivot. If that could apply to `columns` do `.dropna(how='all', axis=1).

```
df.replace(0, np.nan).stack()

0  B   -2.268882
   C    0.337074
1  C    1.340350
2  A   -1.526945
3  A   -1.223816
   C   -2.185926
```

Combine with `.reset_index()` as needed.

To select from a `Series` with `MultiIndex` use `.loc[(level_0, level_1)]`:

```
df.loc[(0, 'B')] = -2.268882
```

Details on slicing etc in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index).

Comment: See updated answer with example and reference to the relevant docs.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a bit ugly way of achieving things, but hey, it works. But this solution has index going from 0 and does not preserve the original order of 'A', 'B', 'C' as in your question, if that matters.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
dff = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,3), columns=list('ABC'))
dff.iloc[0:2,0] = np.nan
dff.iloc[2,2] = np.nan
dff.iloc[1:4,1] = 0 
dff.iloc[2,1] = np.nan
​
# mask to do logical and for two lists
mask = lambda y,z: list(map(lambda x: x[0] and x[1], zip(y,z)))
# create new frame
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
types = []
vals  = []
# iterate over columns
for col in dff.columns:
    # get the non empty and non zero values from current column
        data = dff[col][mask(dff[col].notnull(), dff[col] != 0)]
        # add corresponding original column name 
        types.extend([col for x in range(len(data))])
        vals.extend(data)
        # populate the dataframe
new_df['Types'] = pd.Series(types)
new_df['Vals'] = pd.Series(vals)
​
print(new_df)
#          A         B         C
#0       NaN -1.167975 -1.362128
#1       NaN  0.000000  1.388611
#2  1.482621       NaN       NaN
#3 -1.108279  0.000000 -1.454491
#  Types      Vals
#0     A  1.482621
#1     A -1.108279
#2     B -1.167975
#3     C -1.362128
#4     C  1.388611
#5     C -1.454491
```

I am looking forward for more `pandas/python` like answer myself!